# What is ”semi-flush mount“ lighting?

Tags: lighting

I understand that ”flush mount“ lighting means the fixture hugs the ceiling.

What does "semi-flush mount" lighting mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like a short chandelier as shown in your example. The "semi" can range from the shade being just a couple of inches away from the ceiling to usually no more than 12" away. Bugs love them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, flush mount means the fixture is *in* the ceiling--flush means "on the same plane as". Otherwise it's *surface* mount. (Marketing departments use the term to sound clever when they should say "surface mount".)

[image]
<sub>[Image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.carpentry-tips-and-tricks.com%2FCarpentry-Terms.html&psig=AOvVaw2h-JiSCR4H9NmGyCdekvSl&ust=1638635016566000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjhxqFwoTCICLu6SFyPQCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)</sub>

Examples of flush mounting are recessed cannisters and undercabinet lighting.

So, "semi-flush mount" would mean *partially recessed*. Examples would be eyeball-style recessed cans and channel track lighting.